# I got an "Argument Error" while using conditional statements. How can I fix this error?

Tags: ruby

I tried to solve a simple program. I inserted the code below.

```
puts "By how much degrees you want to trun right?"
print "Enter a number: "
angle=gets.chomp
puts "Got it...now turn right"

if angle < 25
puts "This #{angle} degree is too low to turn right"

elsif angle < 50 && angle >25
puts "This #{angle} degree is somewhat better, but can do better"

elsif angle < 75 && angle >50
puts "This #{angle} is somewhat steep."

elsif angle <= 100 && angle >75
puts "This #{angle} is not recommended. It is toooo steep. Reduce it."

else
puts "Start off!"

end
```

It flashes "Argument error" from line 6. Please help me. I am attaching the screenshot of the error.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9BFg.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't add error messages as images - include them as plain text instead. Adding them as images is inconvenient, wastes bandwidth and makes answering your question for users that use screen readers impossible.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt Point noted! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings with integer.  You need to convert string to integer

```
if angle.to_i < 25
```

Or convert to integer just after reading the value:

```
input = gets

# Check if only numerics were entered
if input =~ /^\d+$/
    angle = input.to_i
else 
    puts "Please enter numeric value"
    exit
end
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but you should tell not to use the redundant `chomp`.

Comment: `'foobar123' =~ /\d+/ # => 6` (truthy)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  Thanks for pointing that out.  Will change regex to `/^\d+$/`

Comment: @sawa  If `chomp` is not used, then, values like `123   ` will get rejected by the regex, unless I fix the regex as well to accept spaces and use `gsub` to get rid of spaces...is that what you are suggesting?  I know that you are suggesting that `to_i` will ignore spaces and will return `0` for alphanumeric values - that would render the whole regex part meaningless anyways.  But I kept it there as 0 may be valid value entered by user

Comment: @sawa I utilized just one concept from this code. The string to integer conversion part- "angle.to_i", and the solution worked well.

Comment: @WandMaker Your regex `/^\d+$/` will not make any difference with or without `chomp` because you cannot input a digit after the endline character. If it is going to match, then it is going to match on the first line.

Comment: @sawa - Thanks. For some reason I was under the impression that `chomp` removed white spaces from around the strings just like Java's [String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)